# How to work with local versions of data objects within a Vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vue.js and vuex to work with data from a backend store that I access via and api. 
My question may be more about semantics and how to actually ask this question and search for better answers because I don't even know the correct terms to be searching on. So here goes...

Within my vue code I make a call to my back end api and it returns a json blob with a block of data that i want to work with in the ui. No problems there. But then I need to slightly modify that data to present it to the user. this entails assessing a few fields and changing them (say, if the value is 0 put in 'n/a', etc.), maybe doing some math on a few fields and so on. Then I present that to the user in a grid/table. I want the user to be able to sort and search on the fields as well. So I may display a field named fullName that comes from the back end but allow the user to sort on a field named lastName that is not actually in the grid.

With that said, here is my question - should I be creating a single 'transformer/reducer' in code to translate the data object coming from the api into what I need for the ui? Or should I be writing multiple filters (by this I mean Vue.js filters that go directly in the html with the '|' pipe) to just modify the fields directly in the html template? 
My concern is the once i modify the object coming back from the api what if I have to post/patch/put back some kind of update - then I need a 'reverse' transformer to get back to an object that my api wants to see.

Generically, I suppose my question could be boiled down to "how do I locally handle an api response object so that I can maintain its 'purity'?"
Or something along those lines. I'm obviously fumbling for the correct terms and that is why i'm struggling to even google for info on this topic. For that I apologize and any help would be appreciated.

Also, I realize there is nothing Vue-specific about my question as this issue could apply to any data-driven ui framework.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. If you'll be using Vuex, you can create filters within a getter that respond to state mutations of filter variables. Then you would be sending the component the polished data. Alternatively, you can directly inject the data from backend into the component, and have the component use computed functions to filter based on user actions. If you perform frequent writes back the the DB, the latter might be easier. If the data stored in Vuex would not be changed often, then that could be the better option.

Comment: By 'filter' I meant a Vue.js pipe '|' filter that goes within the html template. But i think you are using the term filter differently. I edited the question to clear it up slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're asking now. You just want to know if you need to modify the response before making it consumable by the UI. Let's say you're using axios. What I would do in Vue is use the `response.data` object as the data to inject into the vue `data` property. For example, your `response.data` returns an array of objects. You would hardcode a data variable in Vue like this:

```
data () {
    return {
      apiData: []
   }
}
```

and with the API response, set the data array like this:

```
const response = await axios.get(...);
this.apiData = response.data.filter(item => return item.foo === bar);
```

Now `apiData` holds a filtered version of the response data, which was asynchronously retrieved for processing, including the ObjectId's for each object. Note: I would call this during `created(){}` hook to allow time for the GET request to process prior to DOM mounting.You can reference the array objects by the ObjectID within the UI, like this:

```
<div v-for="item in apiData" :key='item_id' :item="item"> 
   <p> {{item.whateverProperty}} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: true. but i must transform the object before showing it - that is my question. if i must tweak the object slightly what is the best place/way to do this?

Comment: That depends on how it needs to be transformed. Are you talking about filtering, string formatting, something else? When I have for transform raw API data from axios I do so right in the return statement. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: i mentioned the types of transformations i needed in the OP. the object you are mounting here could not be posted back to the server because it has changed from the original state. that was the crux of my question.